# How to change only the state of the body property in the material app instead of the whole app being re-rendered?

Tags: flutter

I have a plain app with a bottomNavigationBar to navigate between 4 routes.
I only want to change the state of the body property in the material app when clicked on a bottomNavigationBarItem Instead of the whole app being re-rendered, the title and the bottomNavigationBar should remain constant, and the body of the material app should be updated.

Should i use BLoC library for this?

Comment: First of all, why? That probably won't work as expected

Comment: Well, `BottomNavigationBar` highlights the active route. So it is not designed to be constant. So I agree to @RémiRousselet comment, there's no seemingly reasons for you to keep it constant.

Comment: The bottomNavigationBar would change the color and it won't remain constant depending on the route it is on, I understand, my doubt is that how should the state of the body of the material be changed following the event from the bottomNavigationBarItem, Is BLoC library a solution to this kind of state management. I am a beginner at Flutter so apologies for error in asking the question.

Comment: For e.g. On tapping the 'Home' button in the bottomNavigationBar , the body of the App changes it's state and calls in a set of widgets to display in the body.